# Dataprep - accents and special characters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

How do I solve this problem with accents / special characters in the dataprep? I need this information to appear.

[image]

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataPrep has builtin recipes which allow you to remove or change special characters. For example, you can change accented letters to unaccented ones with [Remove accents in text](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Modify-String-Values_136155014#remove-accents) or you can also replace non recognised characters for another character with [Replace text or patterns](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Modify-String-Values_136155014#remove-a-specific-sub-string).

Below are the steps to change a special character or accented letter.

1. [Create your flow.](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-dataprep#create_a_flow)
2. Add/import your data
3. Click Add a recipe, as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Add-or-Edit-Recipe-Steps_73335362). In your case you can do one or both of the following:

First, in case you have an accented word, go to ***Search Transformations** **> Select Remove accents in text***. Then, select the column, which there are accented words. It will replace the accented words for non-accented ones. Your data your be shown to you so you can check the transformation.

Second, in case you have an non recognised character, go to ***Search Transformations** **> Replace text or patterns >** Select the column you want to transform the data **>** Within ***Find*** write the letter/symbol between single quotes **>** In ***Replace with*** write the letter which will be placed instead*. Finally, preview your data to see the transformation.

**UPDATE:** I was able to load a *.csv* file with the mentioned characters to DataPrep. Below are my steps and sample data:

The .csv file I used had the following content:

```
Test
Non rec. char É
Non rec. char ç
Accented word não
```

In the DataPrep UI home page, click on **Import Data** (top right corner) **Google Cloud Storage** (left part of the screen). Then, find and *select you file* (test just importing one file instead of parametrizing) and click in the add(**+**) symbol. In this step, you can already see the characters, in my case I could see them normally. Finally, click in **Import&Wrangle** and visualise your data. Using the data above, I was able to see the characters properly without any issues.

Comment: I tried to use a function that adjusts accents, but it didn't work. I think it's because of the shape that the accents have become a symbol. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Theorp, can you try to use the **Replace text or patterns** instead? Tell me if it worked for you. Also, would you mind sharing the symbol that it is not being recognised by DataPrep? So I can investigate specifically further.

Comment: I also tested it, but it doesn't change. The Symbol is � , in the csv file it is "É" or "ç".

Comment: @Theorp, I uploaded a *.txt* file with the characters you mentioned and they were recognised by DataPrep. Also, I was able to replace them. Can you tell me where is your data and how you are importing it ? If it is from a file , which format and can you see the characters correctly within the file?

Comment: I created a dataset with parameter to import 3 csv from storage. Enconding is utf-8.

Comment: Ok, I see. Now, if you open the .csv files can you properly see the characters  "É" and "ç" ?

Comment: yes, csv is right. When I create the dataset, it gets the symbol.

Comment: I can separate only the csv column with the problem, and send you the file, in case you want to test it.

Comment: @Theorp, I have updated the question with the test I performed and I did not find any issues. Although, since you can share this column of data with me, can you upload just this column in your question? So I can test with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219970/discussion-between-alexandre-moraes-and-theorp).